# Unable to implement trait for associated type

Tags: rust

Code: https://github.com/xlc/trait-bug

I want to implement a trait for an associated type

```rs
impl From<<baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType> for Foo {
    fn from(_: <baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

But getting error

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<Foo>` for type `Foo`
  --> foo/src/lib.rs:11:1
   |
11 | impl From<<baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType> for Foo {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `foo` (lib) due to previous error
```

Which doesn't make sense to me, as `<baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType` is a concrete type (`u32` in my example)

Is this a compiler bug?

Is there a workaround to achieve my goal?

Note that this is a simplified version of my original code, that is a macro taking a type as input and generate some implementations for this type and associated types.

---

Full code

foo/src/lib.rs

```rs
pub struct Foo;

impl From<<baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType> for Foo {
    fn from(_: <baz::Baz as ::baz::BazTrait>::BazType) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

baz/src/lib.rs

```rs
pub trait BazTrait {
    type BazType;
}

pub struct Baz;

impl BazTrait for Baz {
    type BazType = u32;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an *inline* minimal reproducible example, rather than a link to a git repo containing it. Ideally, you would link to a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) rather than to a repo, additionally to providing the example.

Comment: @jthulhu I am not sure how to create a playground with multiple crates. But will have all the code in the question.

Comment: I get a compiler error when putting the two files in separate crates of the same workspace, but putting them in separate *modules* of the same *crate* works just fine. Maybe it is indeed a compiler bug – I can't see why this would be intended.

Comment: Looks like the compiler doesn't do enough normalization.

Answer (score 1):

This is [issue #51445](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51445), so yes, a compiler bug.